# Jquery search and hash

Tags: jquery, search, hash

How is it possible to make live-search with hashes? 
Now I have a simple jquery search:

```
 $(function(){
/// Start searching
       $("form#search-form").submit(function(e){     
          var hash = 'q=' + encodeURI(document.getElementById('q').value); 
          window.location.hash = hash;
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#results").fadeOut();
            $.ajax({
               type:"GET",
               data: $(this).serialize(),
               url: "search.php",
               success: function(msg){
                      $("#results").html(msg).fadeIn();      
                                     }
                    });     
        }); 
});
```

As you see, I have added here

```
 var hash = 'q=' + encodeURI(document.getElementById('q').value); 
 window.location.hash = hash;
```

to have search-input in hash. So my idea is to type "http://url/#q=word" and have results for "word". Currently my "hash function" is useless, it performs nothing - just adds value to address bar. How could I make jquery perform in that way?

I tried to add

```
 if (window.location.hash != "") {
}
```

but it doesn't help. Or I used to do that wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. may be it is too difficult, but it works:

```
$(function(){
    $("form#search-form").submit(function(e){     
        e.preventDefault();
        var hash = 'search=' + $('#q').val() + '&lang=' + $('.lang:checked').val(); // radio-buttons have class="lang"
        window.location.hash = hash;
        search();
    });

    if (window.location.hash != "") {
        search()
    }

    function search() {
        var hash_arr = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&'),
            values = new Array(),
            i = 0,
            json = '{';

        for (var key in hash_arr) {
            values = hash_arr[key].split('=');
            if (i++ != 0) json += ',';
            json += '"' + values[0] + '":"' + values[1] + '"';
        }

        json += '}';

        $("#results").fadeOut();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: { data : json },
            url: "test2.php",
            success: function(msg){
                $("#results").html(msg).fadeIn();      
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In PHP:

```
$data = (array)json_decode($_POST['data']);
$search = $data['search'];
$language = $data['language'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as for me this rocket science doesn't work at all. I have such errors: Undefined index: search _and_ language — it is `$search` and `$language` lines. Get `{\"search\":\"word\",\"lang\":\"Engl\"}` with `echo $_POST['data']`;

Comment: Try `print_r ($data);` after my first line. What it returns?

Comment: My old search.php looked like: http://pastebin.com/uHN9ajaE As you said I added there: `$data = (array)json_decode($_POST['data']);`
`$search = $data['search'];`
`$language = $data['language'];` and not to have "blank search"
`$var = $data['search'];` After that I replaced `$search_term` with `$search`

Comment: You say that `echo $_POST['data'];` returns `{\"search\":\"word\",\"lang\":\"Engl\"}`. Why there appeared backslashes? May be you using your filter-function after `json_decode`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realised how to fix that. Backslashes are PHP problem, I have updated it and it works well now. And than there is "a small slip": `$language = $data['language'];` has to be `$language = $data['lang'];`.

Comment: But you know, there is a problem with non-latin characters. My database type is `MyISAM`, encoding is `utf8_unicode_ci`. In index page there is `<meta charset="UTF-8">`. But special characters are not working at all: а, б, в, ā, ē, ū, ė, ü, ä. All data in the database is UTF-8, for example: färben or dažyti. May you know the solution?

Comment: What means "special characters are not working"? Do this characters turn into gibberish on the server-side when you enter them in html-form and submit it? Or they deteriorate when writing to the database?

Comment: It means that now after typing non-latin characters I get unknown encoding instead of UTF-8. For example, I enter Russian `красить`, and get such result in URL: `:@0A8BL`, And search doesn't perform too. It says: nothing was found. After German `färben` I get `f%E4rben`, the full url looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8888/kop/#search=f%E4rben&lang=mask`. Lithuanian `ų` looks like `s`, and the script tries to find `s` insted of `ų`.

Comment: So the problem is in Safari 6.0. Chrome 21.0.1180.57 beta and Firefox 11.0 work fine. So it is interesting what to do.

Comment: As fo hash it could be solved like this: `var hash = 'search=' + encodeURI(document.getElementById('q').value) + '&lang=' + $('.lang:checked').val();`. But what about searching? How to avoid wrong charachters?

Comment: What wrong in seaching? Do the correct characters sent to the server after encodeURI()?

Comment: The script is searching `f%E4rben` instead of `färben` — in Safari 6.0. `encodeURI()` only helps to show right characters in address bar, where hash appears.

Comment: It seems that I have to serialize data. But how could I do that?             `data: { data : JSON.stringify(data) },` gives nothing

Comment: May be in `function search()` in `for () {`:  `json += '"' + values[0] + '":"' + encodeURI(values[1]) + '"';` ?

Comment: Now characters encoded in different way: _färben_ looks like `f%C3%A4rben`. And Cyrillic letters are encoded in the same way. I tried to use in PHP as `urldecode($data['search']);` and `rawurldecode($data['search']);` but it has no results. It is still %C3%A4 or so on.

Comment: Try use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI` in `for ()`

Comment: after 5-6 hours, I'll try to do the same thing myself at home

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4739833/kop.zip all my code without database is here. DB Type: MyISAM. Collation: utf8_unicode_ci.

Comment: So.. may be I have found solution: in `index.php` remove all `encodeURI()`. In `search.php` add `urldecode()` to POST-data: `$search = urldecode($data['wirds']);`. My own portable local server are on the flash-drive, but it broken and now I temporarily cant't test encoding in MySQL. But I want to advise: change encoding of `search.php` to `Encode in UTF-8 without BOM` otherwise there will be compatibility issues with encodings whith DB

Comment: It didn't help as well. As I understand the only solution is encode and than decode POST-data in this way Firefox and Chrome will have färben not f%E4rben, but Safari will show f%E4rben or to do vice versa. But thanks a lot. It was really nice to know something new.

Comment: May be need `utf8_general_ci` encoding?

Comment: Ok. I'm still with you, in the near future will try to come up with something else )

Comment: Thanks again. You really helped me. Please see comment below how I have solved that problem. I know that it is very horrible code, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $("form#search-form").submit(function(e){     
        e.preventDefault();
        var hash = 'q=' + encodeURI(document.getElementById('q').value); 
        window.location.hash = hash;
        search();
    });

    if (window.location.hash != "") {
        search()
    }

    function search() {
        var search = window.location.hash.replace('#q=','');

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            data: { 'search' : search },
            url: "test2.php",
            success: function(msg){
                $("#results").html(msg).fadeIn();      
            }
        });
    }
});
```

For better performance use jquery.hashchange plugin

Comment: Thank you. It works fine and that is what I wanted. But you know, in search-form I have also radio-buttons which change language and via that I have different mysql-queries. Is it possible to get data from `<form id='search-form'>` and send it? Because my search.php has such index: `$language = $_GET['language'];`. So it doesn't work with different languages which are on by radio-buttons

Answer (score 1):

This is the way how near everything works fine:
What I have in index:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("form#search-form").submit(function(e){     
      e.preventDefault();
      var hash = '' + encodeURI(document.getElementById('q').value); 
      window.location.hash = hash;

      $("#results").fadeOut();
        $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           data: $(this).serialize(),
           url: "search.php",
           success: function(msg){
                      $("#results").html(msg).fadeIn();      
           }
        });     
   }); 

if (window.location.hash != "") {
    s();
}

function s() {
    var s = window.location.hash.replace('#','');

    if($('#language1').attr('checked')===true) {
    var lang = 'language1';
    }
    else if($('#language2').attr('checked')===true) {
    var lang = 'language2';
    }
    else if($('#language3').attr('checked')===true) {
    var lang = 'language3';
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        data: { 's' : s, language : lang},
        url: "search.php",
        success: function(msg){
            $("#results").html(msg).fadeIn();      
        }
    });
}    


});
```

In PHP:

```
 $search = filter_var($_GET["s"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 $search_term = urldecode($search);
```

So the address bar looks like: 127.0.0.1/dictionary/#search_term
A necessary language comes from cookies — so it is very convenient. The only little issue is as in your scripts (because I've taken pieces of your scripting) search_term changing in address bar. I'll try to explain that. If I take a link 127.0.0.1/dictionary/#word, it shows "word". If I try myself to change in address bar "word" into "other word" it shows nothing — I have to reload page to get a result or just open a new tab/window. I don't know why previous codes didn't work. May it is my mistakes - I have no idea.

Comment: It is fine if all working ) if you need to script is react on adress bar changing use the `jquery.hashchange` plugin. It is very simple: `$(window).hashchange( function(){ // there is code running when you change hash })`. You can download it here: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: Oh! Great. Thank so much. I saw that plugin twice than it seemed me very complicated. Everything is really well. Thank you so much! And sorry for that I wearied you a little :)